# fancyhdr \leftmark, \rightmark entry for \section*

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following latex document and I want to include a section "List of Abbreviations" without a numbering. This should appear in the table of contents as well (it should look similar to the List of Figures and List of Tables sections). 
So far so good, I managed to do it with the `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}` command.

However, I still have a problem with `\fancyhdr` and the `\leftmark` option. It still lists `CONTENTS` in the header of the `List of Abbreviations` section. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt, bibliography=totoc, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{dummy}
\author{my name}
\date{December 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagestyle{fancy}

\tableofcontents 
\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}\itemsep0pt
\acro{ABC}{Alphabet}
\end{acronym}
\newpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\newpage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{subsection 2.2}
\blindtext[4]
\newpage

\section{Section 3}
\blindtext
\newpage


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\section*` does not write to the headers, you have to do that by hand. Add

```
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{List of Abbreviations}
```